# knitr/pandoc: Cross-references to sections, subsections

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

[Environment:  Win 7, R 3.2.3, RStudio, latest]

I have a knitr `.Rmd` document to be an article, where I want to label sections, as in

```
## Mean differences {#sec:meandiff}
```

and then reference that section so it appears in the text as "In Section 3.2, I discuss ..."  I can see that something like this is possible using [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/), and there is some mention of "Internal links" in the pandoc documentation, http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#links, but I can't make it work.  I recall seeing something on this in RStudio-related docs or blogs, but can't find it now.

I tried various things like

```
In Section (@#sec:meandiff) ...
In Section (@sec:meandiff) ...
In Section (#sec:meandiff) ...
```

However, the PDF produced renders this just as

```
In Section (@#sec:meandiff) ...
In Section (???) ..., with: pandoc-citeproc: reference sec:meandiff not found
In Section (#sec:meandiff) ...
```

The `YAML` header I'm using is:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: Moi Meme
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    includes:
        in_header: mystyles.tex
```

There aren't so many such cross-references that I can't do them manually, but if I'm missing something about syntax having them done by `pandoc` would make it easier.

Comment: currently not supported natively for multiple output formats, but there's a [huge discussion...](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/813)

Comment: this might be useful: https://rpubs.com/ajlyons/autonumfigs

Comment: You may try bookdown: https://bookdown.org

Comment: You could also try [pandoc-crossref](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref), works with every output.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, since I'm generating LaTeX,  I can just use it to do the cross-references, while the `\label`s are generated by markdown / pandoc

In the preamble,

```
\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
```

then in the text

```
In \secref{sec:mean-diff} ...
...

## Mean differences {#sec:meandiff}
```

Comment: weird. does not work for me. I still see `??`. do you add the `\newcommand` after `header-includes` ?

Comment: 1. You don't need the `\newcommand` at all; simply use `\ref{sec:meandiff}`.
2. There's a typo: If there's not `-` in the label, there should be no `-` in the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pandoc-secnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-secnos), which is part of the [pandoc-xnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos) filter suite.  The section

```
My Title
========
```

is referenced using `@sec:my-title`.  Alternatively, an id can be explicitly assigned to the header, like

```
My Title {#sec:title}
========
```

which is referred to using `@sec:title`.  The filter is applied by adding `--filter pandoc-secnos` to the pandoc command-line call.

A benefit to this approach is that output in many different formats (LaTeX/pdf, html, epub, docx, ...) is possible.